# Transform a List<Object> to a Map<String, Integer> such that the String is not a duplicate value using Java 8 Streams

Tags: java, list, java-stream, grouping, collectors

We have a `Student` class as follows:

```
class Student {
    private int marks;
    private String studentName;

    public int getMarks() {
        return marks;
    }

    public void setMarks(int marks) {
        this.marks = marks;
    }

    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }

    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }

    public Student(String studentName, int marks) {
        this.marks = marks;
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }
}
```

We have a LIST of Students as follows :

```
List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
studentList.add(new Student("abc", 30));
studentList.add(new Student("Abc", 32));
studentList.add(new Student("ABC", 35));
studentList.add(new Student("DEF", 40));
```

This List needs to be converted into a `HashMap<String, Integer>` such that:

1. the map does not contain any duplicate Student
2. if a duplicate student name is found, his marks shall be added with
   the previous occurrence.

So the output should be:

```
{ABC = 97, DEF = 40}
```

---

I have tried to solve this issue as follows:

```java
Map<String, Integer> studentMap = studentList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                student -> student.getStudentName().toLowerCase(),
                student -> student.getMarks(),
                (s1, s2) -> s1,
                LinkedHashMap::new));
```

But the merge function does not allow me to concatenate the marks and this returns the output as:

```
{abc = 30, DEF = 40}
```

Can someone suggest an efficient solution for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because of an incorrect merge function, you should instead use:

```java
Map<String, Integer> map = studentList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                student -> student.getStudentName().toLowerCase(),
                Student::getMarks,
                (s1, s2) -> s1 + s2, // add values when merging
                LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Answer (score 5):

An alternative solution is to use `groupingBy` with `summingInt`:

```java
Map<String, Integer> studentMap = studentList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                s -> s.getStudentName().toLowerCase(),
                Collectors.summingInt(Student::getMarks)));
```

Answer (score 3):

Your merge function is incorrect. It could be either `(s1, s2) -> s1 + s2` or just `Integer::sum` if you'd rather use a method reference.

Another way to do it is without streams:

```
Map<String, Integer> studentMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
studentList.forEach(s -> studentMap.merge(
                         s.getStudentName().toLowerCase(),
                         s.getMarks(),
                         Integer::sum));
```

This iterates the list of students and uses the `Map.merge` method to group them by name, summing their marks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Collectors.groupingBy(classifier,mapFactory,downstream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.stream.Collector)) method for this purpose:

```java
List<Student> list = List.of(
        new Student("abc", 30),
        new Student("Abc", 32),
        new Student("ABC", 35),
        new Student("DEF", 40));

Map<String, Integer> map = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Student::getStudentName,
                () -> new TreeMap<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER),
                Collectors.summingInt(Student::getMarks)));

System.out.println(map); // {abc=97, DEF=40}
```